# I connected a bipolar stepper motor with an HC-SRO4 distance sensor but the motor doesn't work

Tags: arduino-uno

I connected a bipolar stepper motor with an L293D motor driver and a HC-SR04 distance sensor.

Here's the code:

```
#include<AFMotor.h>
int stepsperrevolution=200;
AF_Stepper motor(stepsperrevolution,1);
int echopin=11;
int trigpin=9;
int dt=2000;
int sensorval;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  motor.setSpeed(10);
  pinMode(echopin,INPUT);
  pinMode(trigpin,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

 digitalWrite(trigpin,LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 digitalWrite(trigpin,HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 digitalWrite(trigpin,LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 sensorval=pulseIn(echopin,HIGH);
 Serial.println(sensorval);

if(sensorval<500){
 motor.step(stepsperrevolution,FORWARD,SINGLE);  
  delay(dt);
   }

}
```

The code works.Although, every time the sersorval prints in the serial monitor, it stops when the value is less than 500, and the stepper doesn't move.

Comment: What happens if you decrease `delay(dt)` ? I'm not sure how much 1 step is, but if there is just one step every 2 seconds it might look like not moving.

Comment: I decreased it already but nothing's changed the motor still doesn't move.

Comment: Has it ever moved (with an example sketch if it exists for your stepper motor) ? To rule out any circuit/programming error.

Comment: put the `motor.step(stepsperrevolution,FORWARD,SINGLE);` outside of the `if` block

Comment: @MichelKeijzers. Yes the stepper motor moved with an example sketch.

Comment: @jsotola I put it outside of the `if` block but the `senorval` reads slowly in the serial monitor

Comment: did the motor run?